# advantage application/x-www-form-urlencoded over application/json

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, http, http-headers

Looking at Facebook, Google, Twitter's POST requests. They all use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as **content-type** to send their request. (Ex: when you like a status on Facebook).

Why don't they use `application/json`?

On production, I've noticed 2 disadvantages with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

1) If I send `a=false&b=0&c=null`. The server doesn't know the original type of the value, whether `false`, `0`, `null` are strings or `boolean`, `int`, `null`.

2) If sending a nested JSON. Usually the server module that does the parsing has to explicitly know which field is  the stringified json, and parse it.

The above 2 issues doesn't exist for `application/json`, because you just cleanly stringify and parse the data around.

So overall, what are really the advantage of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and why the big companies decided to not use `application/json`? Thanks!

Comment: Have you asked the "big companies" that you reference the present question?

Comment: Didn't ask, don't think would be easy to contact.

Comment: There is one big advantage that I came across recently, it is for cross origin requests browser doesn't send the OPTIONS preflight request when you use application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I'm not sure whether this is the exact reason.

Comment: Twitter uses form data when posting tweets but json when posting direct messages. I don't know why, but just for reference: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/new-event